# is it possible to see project files in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure

Just wondering, is it possible to see the directory structure and all the files in a project that is uploaded to Windows Azure? Can we maybe use an ftp program or the developer portal to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup your Azure roles to enable RDP. That way you can log onto the machine and investigate the directory structure, etc.

More information at this MSDN article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg443832.aspx

Comment: +1 for this answer - logging in is very interesting - you see the C, D and E drives...

Answer (score 2):

Or install WebMatrix which lets you view the whole structure of an Azure web app
http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

Answer (score 0):

An old article that explains how to view package contents:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jnak/archive/2009/04/16/digging-in-to-the-windows-azure-service-package.aspx